# how to use opennlp on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, opennlp

I am trying to install opennlp so i can use it for my nlp course project.
I have eclipse kepler on my windows 8 computer 
i read so many online pages about how to install it but no luck
I read 
      http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/discussions/263620
       http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/discussions/263620
and many other links that the website won't allow me to add

but non of them seems to help me
what i did is the following:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\lina>mvn --version
Error: JAVA_HOME not found in your environment.
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

C:\Users\lina>set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51

C:\Users\lina>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T09:37:52-08:00)
Maven home: C:\Apache24\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8", version: "6.2", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

C:\Users\lina>java -jar opennlp-tools-1.5.0.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile opennlp-tools-1.5.0.jar

C:\Users\lina>set opennlp_home=c:\apache-opennlp-1.5.3

C:\>cd ikvm-7.2.4630.5/bin

C:\ikvm-7.2.4630.5\bin>ikvmc -target:library -assembley:opennlp opennlp-maxent-3.0.3.jar jwnl-1.3.3.jar opennlp-tools-1.5.3.jar
IKVM.NET Compiler version 7.2.4630.5
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Jeroen Frijters
http://www.ikvm.net/
fatal error IKVMC5022: Unrecognized option: -assembley:opennlp

C:\ikvm-7.2.4630.5\bin>ikvmc -target:library -assembly:opennlp opennlp-maxent-3.0.3.jar jwnl-1.3.3.jar opennlp-tools-1.5.3.jar
IKVM.NET Compiler version 7.2.4630.5
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Jeroen Frijters
http://www.ikvm.net/
note IKVMC0002: Output file is "opennlp.dll"
warning IKVMC0105: Unable to compile class "opennlp.tools.util.ext.OSGiExtension Loader" (missing class "org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator")
warning IKVMC0100: Class "opennlp.tools.util.ext.OSGiExtensionLoader" not found
warning IKVMC0111: Emitted java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in "opennlp.tools.util.ext.ExtensionLoader.instantiateExtension(Ljava.lang.Class;Ljava.lang.String;)Ljava.lang.Object;" ("opennlp.tools.util.ext.OSGiExtensionLoader")
```

thats basically everything i did
and yet i can't work with opennlp on eclipse kepler
any suggestions..??

I am trying to extract city names from a string then i will convert it to extract them from a file There are no errors or exceptions the run button does not provide run java application option
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
     import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
      import java.io.IOException;
     import java.io.InputStream;
     import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

```
 public class CityFinder {

public String Tokens[];

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, CityFinder {

    CityFinder toi = new CityFinder();
    String cnt;
    cnt="John is planning to specialize in Electrical Engineering in UC Berkley and pursue a career with IBM.";
    toi.tokenization(cnt);
    String cities = toi.namefind(toi.Tokens);
    String org = toi.orgfind(toi.Tokens);

    System.out.println("City name is : "+cities);
    System.out.println("organization name is: "+org);

}
    public String namefind(String cnt[]) {
    InputStream is;
    TokenNameFinderModel tnf;
    NameFinderME nf;
    String sd = "";
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream("en-ner-location.bin");
        tnf = new TokenNameFinderModel(is);
        nf = new NameFinderME(tnf);

        Span sp[] = nf.find(cnt);

        String a[] = Span.spansToStrings(sp, cnt);
        StringBuilder fd = new StringBuilder();
        int l = a.length;

        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            fd = fd.append(a[j] + "\n");

        }
        sd = fd.toString();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sd;
}

public String orgfind(String cnt[]) {
    InputStream is;
    TokenNameFinderModel tnf;
    NameFinderME nf;
    String sd = "";
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream("en-ner-organization.bin");
        tnf = new TokenNameFinderModel(is);
        nf = new NameFinderME(tnf);
        Span sp[] = nf.find(cnt);
        String a[] = Span.spansToStrings(sp, cnt);
        StringBuilder fd = new StringBuilder();
        int l = a.length;
        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            fd = fd.append(a[j] + "\n");

        }

        sd = fd.toString();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sd;

}
public void tokenization(String tokens) {

    InputStream is;
    TokenizerModel tm;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream("en-token.bin");
        tm = new TokenizerModel(is);
        Tokenizer tz = new TokenizerME(tm);
        Tokens = tz.tokenize(tokens);
        // System.out.println(Tokens[1]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a lot of unrelated problems. Let's start from the top:

## JAVA_HOME was not set

Your JAVA_HOME was not set, which you fixed correctly on your own. Good! However, I think if you want to use OpenNLP in Eclipse this is not strictly necessary.

```
C:\Users\lina>set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
```

## JAR file is missing

`Unable to access` means the JAR file is not in there. There is no file called `opennlp-tools-1.5.0.jar` in the folder `C:\Users\lina>`. It's easy to fix: put the JAR file in the folder ;)

```
C:\Users\lina>java -jar opennlp-tools-1.5.0.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile opennlp-tools-1.5.0.jar
```

## Build OpenNLP

Then you try to build OpenNLP. I think building OpenNLP is not necessary to use it. The last error your get means that a dependency of the project you are building is missing.

## Using OpenNLP

Since you use Maven and Eclipse it should be easy to use OpenNLP. Create a new Maven project on Eclipse, open the `pom.xml` file and add the Maven dependency for OpenNLP (as you can find it on the website of OpenNLP):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.opennlp</groupId>
  <artifactId>opennlp-tools</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Now Maven will download OpenNLP and put it on the path of your Eclipse project. you can use it afterwards.

I would go for this solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response.....but the problem is how can i create a maven project i can't see it on my eclipse....??

Comment: Maven is missing in some Eclipse version and must be installed. In your Eclipse go to `Help > Eclipse Marketplace` and search for `Maven`. Install one of the plugins, I use "Maven Integration for Eclipse". Then you should be able to create a new Maven project (or convert an old project to Maven).

Comment: I was able to do everything..... i created a new class with main...i am not having any errors but it seems not able to run what should i do...??

Comment: Well, what do you mean with "it seems not able to run"? Any exception?  How does the class look like?

Comment: Between `<dependencies>...</dependencies>`